# Can't convert to char

Tags: c#

This is just a simple problem that I'm a little stumped on...

As far as I can see I am not actually using a char anywhere as model.children is a `IList<>` and   model.Name is a string however my foreach loop is giving the error that it can't convert char to catalogue.department, if you need any more information plese feel free to ask.

```
        private void DisplayOnWebsiteChecked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var departments = model.Name;
        var departmentChildren = model.Children;

        if (departmentChildren != null)
        {
            int zeroChildren = 0;

            if (departmentChildren.Count.Equals(zeroChildren));
            {
                foreach (Department Children in departments)
                {
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT: This issue has actually be fixed, I will post the fixed code down below as it turns out I actually messed up the code by putting the list in the wrong place.

```
    private void DisplayOnWebsiteChecked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var departments = model.Name;
        var departmentChildren = model.Children;

        if (departmentChildren != null)
        {
            int zeroChildren = 0;

            if (departmentChildren.Count.Equals(zeroChildren));
            {
                foreach (Department Child in departmentChildren)
                {
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `var departments` looks like it's a string.

Comment: It is :) I've fixed it myself thanks for all the replies  guys.

Comment: @HelloWorld I see you've fixed the compilation error, but I suspect your code has a logic error.  If `departmentChildren.Count == 0` then there's no need to call `foreach (Department Child in departmentChildren)`.  The loop won't execute, since the collection is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> model.Name is a string

You have assigned:

```
var departments = model.Name;
```

here department is of type `string` and string implements `IEnumerable<char>`, that is why when you enumerate over it using `foreach`, the item in the `foreach` loop is of type `char`.

and you are using

```
foreach (Department Children in departments)
    {
    }
```

Here Children is of type `char` since department is a string, whereas you have specified it to be of type `Department` that is why you are getting this error.

Comment: +1, but I would add: ... since department is a string *and `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`.*

Comment: I'm glad you responded to my comment because I see now that had forgotten to upvote your answer

Answer (score 1):

`departments` is a `string` from assignment:

```
 var departments = model.Name;
```

THat is why you got `Children` as `char`

Should be:

```
 foreach (Department Children in departmentChildren)
 {
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with this line:

```
foreach (Department Children in departments)
```

`departments` is a string and you're trying to iterate over it, which is treating the string as an `IEnumerable<char>`

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
var departments = model.Name;
```

I suppose that Name is a string then you are enumerating over collection of chars.

Answer (score 0):

**departments** is a `string` and you are trying to treat the `string` as an `IEnumerable<char>`

***As `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`*** and that is why the items in the `foreach loop` is of type `char`.

**AND**

```
int zeroChildren = 0;

if (departmentChildren.Count.Equals(zeroChildren));
{

}
```

So here, ***what is the meaning of `foreach` loop if `departmentChildren` collection is empty...?***